# Can we investigate the cell biology of extinct microorganisms?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, microbiology, fossil

I know that there are microfossils, but not if we can we know about the organelles, genetics or macromolecules of the cells that left them behind.

Comment: Yes we can, provided that we can extract the dna from these organisms and construct their genomes de novo or with respect to genomes of known organisms. That’s typically little bit difficult because the DNA degraded quickly.

Comment: Can you consider adding more details?

Comment: What I would like to know is whether we can find out how organelles used to or came to be by analyzing microfossils. During a presentation about the viral eukaryogenesis hypothesis, the absence of "microfossils showing a gradual development of nuclei" was one of the evidences presented. Until that point, I assumed that cells left nothing but "carcasses" upon fossilization and that little else could be known about them.